# Why the keyup event is not fired on an element in JavaScript while moving the mouse with the left button held down?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keyboard-events, onkeyup

I guess I came across a pretty strange (to me) situation. I have a "keyup" event bound to a div (with `tabindex` set, of course) which contains a Google Map. Basically I need to disable the map dragging functionality when the `shiftKey` is pressed down and enable it again when the key goes up:

```
            mapElement.setAttribute("tabindex", 0);
            mapElement.focus();
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(mapElement, "mouseover", function(e) {
                mapElement.focus();
            });
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(mapElement, "mouseout", function(e) {
                mapElement.blur();
            });            
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(mapElement, "keydown", function(e) {
                var isShift;
                if (window.event) {
                  isShift = !!window.event.shiftKey;
                }
                else {
                  isShift = !!e.shiftKey;
                }                
                if (isShift) {                     
                    map.setOptions({ draggable: false });
                }
            });
```

Now, in order to do so I add a `keyup` event, like the following:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(mapElement, "keyup", function(e) {
                var isShift;
                console.log(e);
                if (window.event) {
                  isShift = !!window.event.shiftKey;
                } 
                else {
                  isShift = !!e.shiftKey;
                }
                if (!isShift) {               
                    map.setOptions({ draggable: true });
                }
            });
```

But this event is not fired if I do the following steps in order:

1. **Press the shift key down while the mouse is over** the map (`mouseover`) (map dragging is disabled here);
2. **While holding down the shift key, press the left button of the mouse and move the cursor on the map**;
3. While moving the cursor on the map with the left button pressed, suddenly **release the shift `key`** (which was held down for all this time) -> *here I expect that the `keyup` event I set is fired and the map becomes draggable again, but instead it's not...*;

It works as it should only if I first release the left mouse button **and then** I raise the `shift` key up. Of, course, my workaround is to add a "mousemove" event, like this:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(mapElement, "mousemove", function(e) {
                if (!e.shiftKey) {
                    map.setOptions({ draggable: true });
                }
            });
```

But could someone more expert than me in JS event handling tell me what's going on here and why that `keyup` wasn't fired?